# PYSWIP not working in pyinstaller executable

Tags: python, prolog, pyinstaller

I've done a project in python and prolog with TKINKTER and PYSWIP. When creating the executable with "pyinstaller -w --onefile main.py" it gives me an error because it is not using PYSWIP library. How can I import this package to my executable? Note: Pyswip is installed via pip

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtJIA.png)